# I feed my turtles maggots..is that ok?

Tags: feeding, safety, turtles

I have redeared sliders a male and a female I found some maggots (kind of embarrassing) but in my kitchen trash I save scraps for my bosses pigs but I didn't go to work for 2 days so kind of forgot it some food fell out on a bucket lid and last night my bfriend noticed them lol he wouldn't touch them and didn't tell me till this morning... When I looked at the lid it was completely covered in maggots. So with out thinking I tossed them in my turtle tank in the water my turtle ate them like a Pac-Man game did I mess up? Are my turtle going to be ok?

Comment: Hey Sharla, check out the selected answer - it's a very good one on turtles and maggots :)
https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5740/are-maggots-appropriate-food-for-a-turtle

Comment: @RebeccaRVT if you use the 'flag' link under the question you can call it out as a duplicate.  This will bring it to the attention of other SE users, via the [Review queue](https://pets.stackexchange.com/review) where it will likely be voted closed as duplicate.  As I have the moderator diamond, it only takes one of my votes, normally it would take 3 votes.